# Locating the source of a function in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I have this annoying issue in my zsh shell where a function is being declared somewhere and that function is named "cp" so it's overriding the normal cp behavior. I'm trying to locate the function declaration but I can't. I already looked in the normal places of .zshrc and the various other sources that are being included in .zshrc but so far nothing.

Other things I've tried:

- `grep -r 'function cp' .` (from ~)
- `whence -f cp` (gives the function definition but not where it's declared from)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, a function can be defined without the `function` keyword so a better search would be

```
grep 'cp()' .*
```

That will search through files such as `.zshrc` and `.profile` and whatnot. If that finds nothing, you might also want to see the various files loaded by `zsh`. These are listed at the very end of `man zsh`:

```
FILES
       $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
       $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
       $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
       $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
       $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
       ${TMPPREFIX}*   (default is /tmp/zsh*)
       /etc/zsh/zshenv
       /etc/zsh/zprofile
       /etc/zsh/zshrc
       /etc/zsh/zlogin
       /etc/zsh/zlogout    (installation-specific - /etc is the default)
```

By default `$ZDOTDIR` should be your `$HOME`. So, this command should find your offending file:

```
grep 'cp()\|cp ()' ~/.zshenv ~/.zprofile ~/.zshrc ~/.zlogin /etc/zsh/zshenv \
 /etc/zsh/zprofile /etc/zsh/zshrc /etc/zsh/zlogin
```

I added the `\|` since you can also have spaces between the function name and the function itself. Finally, [@Dennis points out](https://superuser.com/questions/707354/locating-the-source-of-a-function-in-zsh/707367?noredirect=1#comment903126_707367) that the parentheses can also be omitted if you use the `function` keyword. So, to be even more safe, do this:

```
grep -E 'function cp|cp *\(\)' ~/.zshenv ~/.zprofile ~/.zshrc ~/.zlogin \
  /etc/zsh/zshenv /etc/zsh/zprofile /etc/zsh/zshrc /etc/zsh/zlogin
```

Comment: *`grep` will not search for files beginning with a `.` so it is pretty much useless.* That's not true. When used with the `-r` switch, *grep* will go trough **all** files in directories it encounters. (At least my version of *grep* does.)

Comment: @Dennis I stand corrected, I was thinking of globbing which is completely irrelevant here. Thanks, answer corrected.

Comment: Also, the parentheses are optional if the `function` keyword is used. `grep -E 'function cp|cp *\(\)'` should catch all cases.

Comment: @Dennis fair enough, thanks again, answer edited.

Answer (score 53):

I needed to do this today and found that `whence -v` outputs the file containing the function definition.

```
$ whence -v function_name
function_name is a shell function from /path/to/file
```

Comment: Can you post your version of zsh? I don't see output like that with zsh `5.0.2`

Comment: Worked for me with zsh 5.3

Comment: Works for me with 5.1.1.

I also want to add that, though it looks like another response was flagged as the answer, I'd recommend this one first.  It's a quick, clean solution that uses built in functionality to do precisely what was asked for.

Answer (score 8):

Newer versions of zsh (since 5.4, added in commit [`34f70c5`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/34f70c5dc08bbecd20fbb8a1797851103fbad45e)) support the `$functions_source` array as part of the `zsh/parameter` module (documentation: `man zshmodules`):

> #### `functions_source`
>
> This readonly associative array maps names of enabled functions to the name of the file containing the source of the function.
>
> For an autoloaded function that has already been loaded, or marked for autoload with an absolute path, or that has had its path resolved with ‘`functions -r`’, this is the file found for autoloading, resolved to an absolute path.
>
> For a function defined within the body of a script or sourced file, this is the name of that file. In this case, this is the exact path originally used to that file, which may be a relative path.
>
> For any other function, including any defined at an interactive prompt or an autoload function whose path has not yet been resolved, this is the empty string. However, the hash element is reported as defined just so long as the function is present: the keys to this hash are the same as those to `$functions`.

So, you can do

```
echo $functions_source[cp]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Terdon's answer](https://superuser.com/a/707367/195224) already gave you the appropriate `grep` command to catch all possible variants of a function definition.

I want to add two more points.

1. To get a list of files, which are *actually* read in (e.g. a non-standard file might be sourced by another file!), you can invoke `zsh` with the `SOURCE_TRACE` option enabled:

   ```
   $ zsh -o sourcetrace
   +/etc/zshenv:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zcompdump:1> <sourcetrace>
   +/home/user/.zshrc-last:1> <sourcetrace>
   ```
2. With this ,,grep-approach'' you won't catch functions which are *autoloaded* via the `autoload` builtin. So, do a check of your `fpath`, too:

   ```
   $ for i ($fpath) { ls -l "$i"/cp }
   ```