# find file containing a function

Tags: bash, zsh, sh

I would like to know a way to get the file that contains a function that is accessible because it's been sourced in shell. For Bash and ZSH.

For example when I want to find out the source of function `git_showhidden` it prints the function but not the file.

```
$ which git_showhidden
git_showhidden () {
    files=($(git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]" | sed 's/h //'))
    echo "${files[@]}"
}
```

Of course I could search for the string, but that is boring and slow.
`which`, `whence` and `type` do not deliver what I need.

Comment: There is no record in `bash` of the file where a function, variable or alias is defined. You need to look through the files that are executed during the start-up of an interactive `bash` session: `/etc/profile`,`/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `$HOME/.profile` and `$HOME/.bash*`, though I'm not sure this is an exhaustive list; `zsh` will have a similar set of files. Alternatively, if an installation created the function, look at the files installed by your `git` package(s), which should include where your function is defined.

Comment: Talking about the startup order of Shell files [this](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) might be a good hint. And remembering that a function _knows_ everything, that a parent does (as it's been stated [here](https://www.prismnet.com/~dierdorf/alias.html), I just might have to search the parents for evidence... (The function quoted above serves merely as a sample to show a typical output of `which` in that case.)

Comment: I was hoping that there is an easier way to find out.

Comment: A similar question focusing on zsh: https://superuser.com/q/707354/195224 and according to Wiil's answer there: `whence -v git_showhidden` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As for whence: I seem to have to wait for the next release (via Debian). On ZSH 5.0.7 I just get `git_showhidden is a shell function`.

Comment: Interesting links. If you run `bash -x` you will see all the commands executed on start-up. I haven't found any way in Ubuntu to log the commands to a file, as redirection or piping to `tee` or `less` suppresses the debug information; so you need a big screen buffer in order to capture on screen the whole log, which you can then select and copy to a file for browsing and searching.

Comment: The output of `zsh -x` could get logged with `zsh -x > xzsh.log 2>&1`. That is already quite helpful. This does not work for bash though.

Answer (score 0):

Only part of an answer, but for [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), `type` does exactly what you need.

Example:

```
$ type extract
extract is a shell function from /usr/share/oh-my-zsh//plugins/extract/extract.plugin.zsh
```

You may pipe its output to `sed "s/.*is a shell function from //g"` to get the path only (this may have some issues, but should work for most of the output).