# How to remove a permanent alias to gcc to a version that no longer exists?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

My gcc is currently linked to gcc-4.8, every time I run gcc, it says:

```
zsh: command not found: gcc-4.8
```

and my alias list contains `gcc=gcc-4.8`

and my gcc version is 5.

I have searched lots of places. I have looked in the `.bashrc` file (one in home and another in root). I have no idea where is this permanent alias is from. This is not letting me install some files that need `gcc`.

Comment: May be of help: https://superuser.com/questions/707354/locating-the-source-of-a-function-in-zsh -- substitute the function name with your alias definition.

Comment: Why are you looking at `.bashrc`? Zsh does not source this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `zsh -x`!

If you ever need to know where some function or alias was set, or literally anything else that goes on with Zsh, the trace feature is a godsend. Do this:

```
% zsh -x &> trace
% exit
% grep 'alias.*gcc-4.8' trace
```

You (should) be given something along these lines:

```
+/path/to/some/file:[line]> alias 'gcc=gcc-4.8'
```

Use the contents of the `trace` file to determine where the culprit is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update-alternatives? 
https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/733411

To find, where your alias is defined, you could recursively grep to find the file, where "gcc-4.8" is mentioned. To search in /etc:

```
grep -lr gcc-4.8 /etc/
```

Or in your home folder:

```
grep -lr gcc-4.8 ~
```

You also could find, which gcc is used with:

```
which gcc
```

You also could reset your alias with `alias gcc=gcc` and you could add this in to your .bashrc to overwrite on bash login.

Comment: There's no need to guess or result to brute force searches, just use `zsh -x`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```bash
grep gcc < ~/.bashrc
```

If you see some output, run this:

```bash
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to search for GCC. Once you find the old alias, remove it, save the file (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and start a new shell.

If you don't see any output, try:

```bash
nano ~/.bash_history
```

and repeat the above steps.

## If all else fails

Try

```bash
command gcc
```

when you would normally use `gcc`. You shouldn't have to use this, but it works.

Comment: when I do command gcc, I get this instead
zsh: command not found: gcc

Comment: @user1888587 try `command gcc5`

Comment: There is no need to guess what file may contain the alias definition. Just use `zsh -x`; see my answer.